# Como faço para fazer um case when no load data infile?

Tags: mysql

Preciso fazer uma `replace` da mesma coluna de varias string distintas, fazer um `load data infile`.

Só que dá um erro de sintaxe na linha 12 onde tem o primeiro case, alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado o código esta abaixo?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/temp/reportes/fornecedor.csv'
                            INTO TABLE reparo.pn_digitron
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            ENCLOSED BY '"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                            IGNORE 1 LINES
                            (@modelo,@tipo,
                            @part_number,@fornecedor,@descricao_bom)
                            SET
                            `Modelo` = trim(@modelo),
                            `tipo` = trim(@tipo),
                            case when `part_number` = 'DT' then
                            `part_number` = trim(replace(@part_number, 'DT', 'MB')),
                            when `part_number` = 'NB' then 
                            `part_number` = trim(replace(@part_number, 'NB', 'MB')), 
                            when `part_number` = 'EBG' then
                            `part_number` = trim(replace(@part_number, 'EBG', 'MB')),
                            when `part_number` = 'SMALL' then
                            `part_number` = trim(replace(@part_number, 'SMALL', 'SB')) end,
                            `fornecedor` = trim(@fornecedor),
                            `descricao_bom` = trim(@descricao_bom);
```

Answer (score 0):

O `CASE WHEN` não te permite definir uma expressão de `SET` inteira como você tentou fazer. Você só pode usá-lo do lado direito da atribuição, assim:

```
...
SET
    `Modelo` = trim(@modelo),
    `tipo` = trim(@tipo),
    `part_number` = CASE 
                      WHEN `part_number` = 'DT' THEN trim(replace(@part_number, 'DT', 'MB'))
                      WHEN `part_number` = 'NB' THEN
                      ...
                      END
```